# Can PHP and Apache server comunicate at run time to control-business-flow?

Tags: php, apache, runtime

For example, to change environment variables from PHP and flow-control Apache accordingly, like:

From PHP:

```
$_SERVER['test'] = true;
```

From Apache:

```
<if "%{test}">
    ..
</if>
```

From what I see so far, Apache evaluates at server-start-time NOT at run-time.

Comment: Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

Comment: What's your desired end goal here?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Buy isin't APACHE evalute $_ENV only at startup?

Comment: No - it can evaluate at any point.

Comment: @dagon Security. To do RewriteRule after PHP check if user is authorized

Comment: @JayBlanchard The change is for each "session" or for all requests?

Comment: It depends on how you use it. Typically the variables would be set for all requests, but I feel that you could - although I don't know why - set them differently for each session.

Comment: You shouldn't use environment variables for authorized users, just use `$_SESSION` and create an appropriate key/pair for authorized users.